# Can I deploy xadisk as a JCA resources in Jetty?

Tags: java, jetty, jndi, jca

what I want is merge file transaction and db transaction into one. and our application is running on Jetty. but Jetty isn't must. we hope transaction can running standalone, not depend on server.  depend on server is acceptable. but it's not the first choice. 
   currently, I use atomikos to manage the transaction.

what I currently understanding is:

1. is there any example how integer atomikos and XADisk without using
   enlist? I can use enlist work. but it's a little ugly in our system.
   in the db part, we don't use enlist method. we use hibernate, and
   warp the datasource by atomikos for hibernate,  I hope use the same
   solution for xadisk if possible.
2. I try to use JNDI(Unfortunately, I'm not very familiar with this
   too. ). I try to bind XADiskConnectionFactoryImpl to JNDI, but I
   found I need ConnectionManager to instance
   XADiskConnectionFactoryImpl, but I don't know how to get. Ｉ know it
   for server, but I don't know how. the follow is my configuration in
   Jetty

   ```
   <New  id="xadisk"  class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource">
    <Arg>xadisk</Arg>
    <Arg> 
      <New  class="org.xadisk.connector.outbound.XADiskConnectionFactoryImpl">
      </New>
    </Arg>
   ```

Comment: I see lots of 'jetty' in here but practically nothing that actually deals with jetty itself, its not clear if you're just having a jndi configuration issue or something else...and if you are having jndi issues, it sounds like its less jndi and more you're missing a requirement of the xadisk impl?  very confusing to follow, perhaps you can expand on your actual problem and include some stack traces or something?  or just dig deeper into the xadisk configuration side of things...

Comment: thanks for you advices. what I ask is two. the first one is how to config xadisk as JCA resources or JNDI resources in Jetty. which meaning use Jetty configuration to make JNDI as a datasource

Comment: another requirement is initialize the xadisk's JCA adapter and bind it into jndi.